# Flex : Changing the appearance of a disabled checkbox

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox

A disabled checkbox in flex looks very "light" colored, almost invisible.
Is it possible to make it look like an enabled checkbox which does not
do anything on a click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disabledIconColor="0x000000" does a pretty good job.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a super quick fix, but you can set the disabledSkin (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/controls/Button.html#style:disabledSkin) style of the checkbox. If you don't know how to skin flex components, this is a good place to start: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/skinning_components/.